# Generating 3D points along a cylinder surface with a non-uniform distribution

Tags: python, math, geometry

I am trying to randomly generate points along the curved surface of a cylinder that has a y up-axis. Following a SO question of creating points along a 2D circle, I have

```
def point(h, k, r):
    theta = random.random() * 2 * pi
    global x
    global y
    x = h + cos(theta) * r
    y = k + sin(theta) * r
```

given the cylinder's (h,k) origin point (0, -21.56462) and r (radius = 7.625). I then made these points 3D by generating a z point within my range (-2.35, 12.31). However, this got me half the way there because the final result was a cylinder but rotated 90 degrees clockwise.

[Image of generated cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAyRI.png)

What formula can I use that will generate the points in the correct direction? I am not that familiar with trigonometry, unfortunately. Thanks in advance!

THE SOLUTION:

```
def point(h, k, r):
    theta = random.random() * 2 * pi
    global x
    global z
    x = h + cos(theta) * r
    z = k + sin(theta) * r
```

The new (h,k) origin is now (x,z) where x and z are the coordinates for the center of the cylinder and y is randomly generated within its appropriate height range. The vector is still (x,y,z).

[Updated generated cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfQEU.png)

Comment: I believe you can fix your problem by assigning your third random value (-2.35, 12.31) as the Y value of the random point, instead of the Z value. Use the two points from your `point` function as the X and Z values so that the circles will be parallel to the XZ plane, as opposed to using them as the X and Y values.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I will edit my question with the code and explanation.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Better post the solution as an answer so people will see that this question is answered.

Comment: @NicoSchertler thanks for that! My first post, so wasn't sure what to do. It's updated now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THE SOLUTION:

(thanks to David Huculak)

```
def point(h, k, r):
    theta = random.random() * 2 * pi
    global x
    global z
    x = h + cos(theta) * r
    z = k + sin(theta) * r
```

The new (h,k) origin is now (x,z) where x and z are the coordinates for the center of the cylinder and y is randomly generated within its appropriate height range. The vector is still (x,y,z).

[Updated Generated cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HMAW.png)